# CSS Media Query not Working (Meta View Port Added)

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have my website looking just how I want it on a desktop. I have come to adding a media query today thinking it would be as straight forward as its been in the past for me, but it doesn't want to work for me this time. I have added the meta view port (automatically added with Emmet shortcut '!') but no dice.

I just want to switch the flex direction to column and the divs to 100vw. I added the yellow colour here as a visual reference for myself.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 720px) {
  text__main {
    min-width: 100vw;
    background-color: yellow;
    
  }
  container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
  menu {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Any guidance would be massively appreciated. The website is currently an eyesore and reflects badly on the content.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you wrote your [CSS selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) incorrectly. Instead of text__main try .text__main and so on with other selectors (menu could be an HTML tag, so maybe it should stay as it is now).

Comment: Perfect. It's always something that has me kicking myself lol. Thanks a lot.